# How to implement a test phase in Paypal Recurring Payments?

Tags: paypal

I have a question to recurring payments in paypal: I have express checkout payments integrated into my project. After I complete a payment, I will initialize the recurring payments. As long as I give the correct amount (e.g. 2.99 Euro) to express checkout payment, everything works fine. Now I would like to integrate a test phase, in which a user don't pay for the first month but for month 2, 3 and so on. Unfortunately I cannot do an express checkout payment and pass the value of EUR 0, then the error "invalid amount" appears.

How do you implement such a test phase with Paypal? I have seen Spotify does it like that.  There I don't pay anything for the first month, but in the second month I payed 9.99 euros (without doing anything, they take my payment details when I register for Spotify). Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a trial period? I had mine working
in US dollars using a trial period.  I tried it
using PayPal sample code and the sample worked
for EUR too. I am using the new X.comm PayPal SDK 
in Php. In that SDK, go to samples/RecurringPayments/
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php. Up at the top
there is a line of code where you can change the 
currency.

```
//$currencyCode = "USD";
$currencyCode = "EUR";
```

Then type in the URL yourdomain/your_merchant-sdk-php/samples/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.html.php to run the sample. Choose 0.0 for the trial period amount. It should come back as success.